# Fastest way to pull rows from the database based on attribute weights

Tags: database, algorithm

I've got a table with ~80 columns that are all binary values. In my application I'm able to calculate weights for each one of those attributes. I'd like to be able to pull out the top n rows where the sum of the binary value * it's weight was the highest.

E.g.

SELECT id, CAST(attribute_1 AS int) * weight_1 + CAST(attribute_2 AS int) * weight_2 AS score
WHERE some_filtering_conditions
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT n

While this works it isn't anywhere near as fast as I'd like it.

Currently everything is stored in Postgres, but I'd be open to other database suggestions. Right now there's about 8000 rows in this table and it isn't likely to grow by too much so pulling it all into memory isn't beyond reason, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Well, the query can only order by the function(weight * value) after it has evaluated the function **for all rows** in the table. The only way to avoid this would be to cache the function result in the table, and use triggers or such to maintain it.

Comment: Unfortunately the weights are different for every user and changed based on other actions they have with the system :(.

Comment: In that case you could create a [8000*nuser] table to store the individual caches. Anything goes ...